# Copying image PropertyItems using C#

Tags: c#, exif

I'm trying to copy EXIF data from one image to another, using something like this:

```
foreach (PropertyItem item in SourceImage.PropertyItems)
{
    DestinationImage.SetPropertyItem(item);
}
```

This seems to work for 90% of the EXIF data. However, it's not getting some basic ones (like Camera Maker and Camera Model). My question is, how can I ensure I'm getting all the EXIF data?

I'm willing to look into 3rd party EXIF libraries, but they have to be free and have to WRTITE EXIF back to images, and not just READ.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The cheapest and fastest way would probably just be to compare the EXIF header binary data after you copy the images. It might even be faster just to overwrite the binary data on the buffer of your copied image. That way, byte for byte, you are the same.